# Django - Message translation in template still show original language version

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Translations in the same function for form.error work and messages are displayed in a different language, but for "messages" the text is still displayed in English in the template

views.py

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

form.errors['__all__'] = form.error_class([_('Bad pin')])
```

Works, i see translated version in my language

```
messages.add_message(self.request, messages.INFO, _('Bad pin'))
```

Didn't work, in the template after entering {{message}}, I see the English oryginal version

```
Settings.py

'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
"account.middleware.LocaleMiddleware",
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
"account.middleware.TimezoneMiddleware",
```

Comment: Did you generate a translation?

Comment: Yes, i run python3 manage.py makemessages -l pl and  python3 manage.py compilemessages -l pl

Answer (score 0):

Change from

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
```

to

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
```

Solve problem